# Puppet warns that keys need to be qualified with the name of the module

Tags: function, key, puppet, ubuntu-20.04

We have the Puppet (warning):

`Module 'profiles': Value returned from data_hash function 'yaml_data', when using location '.../data/modules/profiles/3dtools.yaml', must use keys qualified with the name of the module`

What does this warning means?

Any ideas?

Thx in advance!

Comment: `data_hash` and `yaml_data` suggest that this message is associated with Hiera in some way, but there is not enough information to determine any details.  Possibly your Puppet installation is corrupt, possibly you are engaging a custom Hiera backend that is incompatible with your Puppet version, possibly there is a flaw in your Hiera data and / or one in Puppet, possibly you have interposed a custom function that conflicts with Puppet internals, possibly something altogether else is going on.  We'll need a [mre] to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your `3dtools.yaml` file there is at least one entry that does not follow the format of

```
<module_name>::<parameter>: <value>
```

or

```
<module_name>::<subclass_name>::<parameter>: <value>
```

For example

```
---
profile::hiera_test::ssl: false
profile::hiera_test::backups_enabled: true
```

This warning appeared for me and I was missing the double colon "::" on one of my lines. A simple typo, but once I corrected the entry, the warning went away.

More information: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/hiera_quick.html#values_common_data

Comment: It is not wrong for an Hiera data source to provide data having keys whose forms differ from the one serving automatic data binding.  Hiera is more general than just supporting data binding.  The OP's data may well have contained a bad key, but that's not the only possibility, and the situation is more nuanced than this answer suggests.

Comment: Also, there is only one format for keys for automatic data binding.  It is `<fully-qualified_class_name>::<parameter_name>`.  A lot of fully-qualified class names contain double colons, but not all of them.  Some contain more than one set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this might be too restrictive in the case of roles or profiles.  It is not an uncommon practice to have a "message" entry to aid in troubleshooting.  Something like:

---

message: 'This is the development branch common.yaml in the profiles module'

Yes, the --explain flag manages this operation very well, but having an extra lookup to see just what you're getting and from where is nice.